# Прошу помочь разобраться с ошибкой _() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, python-2.x, rss

Пытаюсь сократить ссылки получаемые с другого сайта с помощью bitly.

```
for item in rss.findAll('item')[::-1]:
    title_raw = item.title.string
    date_end = title_raw.find(' - ')

    if date_end != -1:
        item_day = int(title_raw[0:title_raw.find(' ')])
        title = title_raw.string[date_end+3:]
        day_word = u'сегодня' if item_day == current_day.day else u'завтра'

    link_raw = item.guid.string

    link = bitly.shorten(link_raw[0:link_raw.find('?')])
```

После чего получаю ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Git/announce_cinema/holiday.py", line 47, in  link =
>   bitly.shorten(link_raw[0:link_raw.find('?')]) TypeError: _() takes
>   exactly 0 arguments (1 given)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

Comment: Для начала — что такое bitly и откуда вы его достали?

Comment: Сервис сокращения ссылок https://bitly.com/ , у которого есть свой api. К апи подключается выше приведенного кода

Comment: Это я уже понял, а что конкретно за api-то? Гугл говорит, их несколько

Comment: 1. Вероятно нет знака вопроса в `link_raw`, поэтому `find('?')` может вернуть `-1` поэтому `bitly.shorten()` получает `link_raw[0:-1]`. Проверьте это значение (является ли URLом?) 2. То что это приводит к TypeError а не ValueError вероятно является багом в bitly (где вы этот пакет взяли?) 3. Вы могли бы использовать urlparse модуль чтобы нужную часть URL получить. Также используйте [feedparser модуль](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/introduction.html) для распознавания rss вместо попытки сделать это руками с помощью BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Использую bitly_api
https://github.com/bitly/bitly-api-python

Comment: Приведите полный traceback и результат `print(repr(link_raw))`